# Hibernate session.get() is always returning null

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T019_STAFF_PROFILE")
public class UserDetails implements Serializable
{
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = -723583058586873479L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "STAFF_ID", columnDefinition="CHAR(8)")
    private String              loginId;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", columnDefinition="CHAR(8)")
    private String              password;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAM")
    private String              firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAM")
    private String              lastName;

    @Column(name = "BUS_OG_CD" , columnDefinition="CHAR(3)")
    private String              profile;
```

---

```
public UserDetails getLoginDetails(String loginId)
    {
        UserDetails object =(UserDetails)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(UserDetails.class, loginId);
        return object;
    }
```

---

Comment: `STAFF_ID` column is `CHAR(8)`, not `VARCHAR(8)`. Is your `String loginId` exactly the same 8 symbols?

Comment: STAFF_ID is declared as CHAR (8) in my oracle DB.

Comment: do you consider writing a question body?

Answer (score 0):

Check the database to see if the value really exists in the database.

`SELECT * FROM T019_STAFF_PROFILE WHERE STAFF_ID = <the value of **loginId**>`

Answer (score 0):

For Time being, created a temp user with exactly 8 chars and then tried to access the same user through hibernate. I was able to fetch the record.

1. @Id
   @Column(name = "STAFF_ID", columnDefinition="CHAR(8)")
   private String              loginId;

   This is my column definition. Is there any thing that i need to declare?

Answer (score 0):

Found something interesting. Correct me if the approach is wrong.

Since my db column is declared as CHAR(8), to hibernate, i should always pass 8 char to get the results.

So, if your STAFF_ID is 3 chars, append 5 empty chars and the pass it to hibernate which will fetch your record.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please, update your question instead of posting answers.

Answer (score -1):

## Session.get(Class clazz, Serializable id)

> Return the persistent instance of the given entity class with the
>   given identifier, or null if there is no such persistent instance. (If
>   the instance is already associated with the session, return that
>   instance. This method never returns an uninitialized instance.)

So check if data exists in your database or not.

Comment: Any exception? And which database you are using?

Comment: No Exceptions. I am using oracle